# Autoadapt height of View

Tags: ios, swift, view

I m building a chat View in xCode with swift language.
I m create two custom cell one to sender message and another one to received message. The problem is when the text of message is greater than the width of the screen of iPhone. Then I need to configure the two views to increase the height if the text is too big.
So this is my view:
[image]
I configured the height of View Lbl Message >= 30 but if you see xCode set to RED that constraint and for me the error is in that part.

Anyway this is the result of my iPhone when application stil running:
[image]

If you check with more attention after the text "mio" in the blue cell you can see that there are other text but it is not displayed.

**EDIT**

I added ChatVC controller where is the UITableView:

```
//
//  ChatVC.swift
//  appUser
//
//  Created by mac on 11/10/21.
//  Copyright © 2021 Michele Castriotta. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SDWebImage
import SwiftyJSON
import AVFoundation

class ChatVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var aggiorna:Bool = false
    var arrMsgs:[ChatModel] = []
    var receiverId = ""
    var storeName = ""
    var userName = ""
    var userId = ""
    var strReason = ""
    var strReasonID = ""
    var strType = "User"
    var strRighTitle = ""
    var strPrname = ""
    var daNotifica:Bool = false
    
    @IBOutlet weak var viewWriteMessage: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitleChat: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtMessage: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewChat: UITableView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.showProgressBar()
        self.tableViewChat.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
        self.viewWriteMessage.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius: 22, borderColor: nil, borderWidth: nil)
        userId = kUserDefault.value(forKey: USERID) as! String
        self.lblTitleChat.text = self.storeName
        wsGetChatAgain()
    }
    
    func wsGetChatAgain()  {

     //   showProgressBar()
        var paramDict : [String:AnyObject] = [:]
        paramDict["receiver_id"]  =   receiverId as AnyObject
        paramDict["sender_id"]  =   userId as AnyObject

        CommunicationManeger.callPostServiceReturnJson(apiUrl: RouterProd.get_chat.url(), parameters: paramDict,  parentViewController: self, successBlock: { (responseData, message) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let chats = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseChatModel.self, from: responseData as! Data)
                    if(chats.status == "1") {
                        self.arrMsgs  = chats.result
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               // Main thread, called after the previous code:
                               // hide your progress bar here
                            self.tableViewChat.reloadData()
                            self.hideProgressBar()
                        }
                        //self.scrollToBottom()
                        //self.lbl_ChatReason.text = self.strReason
                    }
                }catch{
                   print("errore durante la decodifica dei dati: \(error)")
                    self.hideProgressBar()
                   //Utility.noDataFound("Errore", tableViewOt: self.tableViewChat, parentViewController: self)
               }
            }
        }, failureBlock: { (error : Error) in
            Utility.showAlertMessage(withTitle: EMPTY_STRING, message: (error.localizedDescription), delegate: nil,parentViewController: self)
            self.hideProgressBar()
        })
        self.aggiorna = true
        self.aggiornaChat()
    }
    
    func aggiornaChat(){
        if(aggiorna){
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 15.0, execute: wsGetChatAgain)
        }
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnBack(_ sender: Any) {
        self.aggiorna = false
        if(self.daNotifica == false){
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }else{
            Switcher.updateRootVC()
        }
        
    }
    
    //MARK: - Table View Methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrMsgs.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let message = self.arrMsgs[indexPath.row]
        var messaggio = message.chatMessage
        var orario = Utility.getDateStringFromString(dateString: message.date, inputFormate: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", outputFormate: "HH:mm")
        
        
        if(message.senderID == userId){
            //messaggio inviato dal utente
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatCell
            cell.lblMessage.text = messaggio
            cell.lblTime.text = orario
            var maximumLabelSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 280, height: 9999)
            var expectedLabelSize: CGSize = cell.lblMessage.sizeThatFits(maximumLabelSize)
            // create a frame that is filled with the UILabel frame data
            var newFrame: CGRect = cell.lblMessage.frame
            // resizing the frame to calculated size
            newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height
            // put calculated frame into UILabel frame
            cell.lblMessage.frame = newFrame
            return cell
        }else{
            //messaggio inviato dallo o runner
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatCell2", for: indexPath) as! ChatCell2
            cell.lblMessage.text = messaggio
            var maximumLabelSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 280, height: 9999)
            var expectedLabelSize: CGSize = cell.lblMessage.sizeThatFits(maximumLabelSize)
            // create a frame that is filled with the UILabel frame data
            var newFrame: CGRect = cell.lblMessage.frame
            // resizing the frame to calculated size
            newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height
            newFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width
            // put calculated frame into UILabel frame
            cell.lblMessage.frame = newFrame
            cell.lblTime.text = orario
            return cell
        }
        
    }

    @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
        if txtMessage.text == "Scrivi qui..." || txtMessage.text!.count == 0 {
            GlobalConstant.showAlertMessage(withOkButtonAndTitle: APPNAME, andMessage: "Per favore scrivi del testo...", on: self)
        } else {
            wsSendMessage()
        }
    }
    
    func wsSendMessage()  {
        self.showProgressBar()
        
        var localTimeZoneIdentifier: String { return TimeZone.current.identifier }
        var paramDict : [String:AnyObject] = [:]
        paramDict["receiver_id"]   =  receiverId as AnyObject
        paramDict["sender_id"]    =   userId as AnyObject
        paramDict["chat_message"]  =  self.txtMessage.text! as AnyObject
        paramDict["timezone"]  =  localTimeZoneIdentifier as AnyObject
        paramDict["request_id"]  =   strReasonID as AnyObject
        paramDict["type"]  =   strType as AnyObject
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        var dataOra = formatter.string(from:Date())
        paramDict["date_time"]  =   "\(dataOra)" as AnyObject
        
        CommunicationManeger.callPostService(apiUrl: RouterProd.insert_chat.url(), parameters: paramDict,  parentViewController: self, successBlock: { (responseData, message) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData)
                print(swiftyJsonVar)
                if(swiftyJsonVar["result"].stringValue == "successful") {
                    self.txtMessage.text = ""
                    self.view.endEditing(true)
                    self.wsGetChatAgain()
                }
                self.hideProgressBar()
            }
        }, failureBlock: { (error : Error) in
            Utility.showAlertMessage(withTitle: EMPTY_STRING, message: (error.localizedDescription), delegate: nil,parentViewController: self)
            self.hideProgressBar()
        })
    }
}
```

This is chatCell class

```
import UIKit

class ChatCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblMessage: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewLblMessage: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTime: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.viewLblMessage.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius: 10, borderColor: nil, borderWidth: nil)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a height constraint. Instead, set the leading, top, trailing and bottom of `Lbl Message` to it's parent view and set the number of lines of `Lbl Message`  to zero.

Comment: Looks more like a `UITableView` automatic cell height issue. Why don't you post your table view code?

Comment: @GustavoConde that is not the problem here. He just didn't set the constraints properly.

Comment: I m just add my class

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the size of the text, don't add height to the view. You should add your constraints without adding height

Comment: I removed height but I m not able to display the text if I load my view